# How to add tax included value price when I set product specific prices

Tags: mysql

In my prestashop backoffice I had set the all products prices as `tax_incl` and for that products `tax_incl` is coming. Now I have to change my pricing to specific pricing but in specific pricing I can see only an option like `tax_excl` price to enter, Because of that the tax is calculating and I want to know how it can be made to `tax_incl`. Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: How is this question related to php ?

Comment: it is on prestashop 1.6